# Self signed ssl I created for localhost cannot be trusted even though I have already imported it to chrome

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, openssl, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate

I am creating https server side that I am using to practice OAuth to Instagram which requires https.

I generated a certificate using ssl by running the script from the following link: https://gist.github.com/bjanderson/075fadfccdd12623ab935e57eff58eb4

The script ran just fine and I received all the expected files. I've imported the ca.crt to my chrome under the trusted root certification authorities but chrome still won't trust it. Is the import location appropriate since chrome has many different sections that ca.crt could be imported to.

I get the following errors:

Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address.

Certificate - missing This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

How do i fix these two issues and get my chrome to trust my self signed certificate?

Comment: Chrome doesn't accept certificates issued to _localhost_.  Also, as the error message states you need to use certificates which include a _Subject Alternative Name_ extension.  The scripts you use don't include this extensions (as can be gleaned from reading the comments below the scripts).

Comment: Actually I issued mine to 127.0.0.1. Can you explain to me what subject alt name is used for? How do i make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Subject Alternative Name* is, as it says, where alternative names for the subject are listed.  It is an improvement on the *Subject* field because it allows multiple subject names whereas *Subject* only allows one.  Modern browsers only look at the *Subject Alternative Name* extension and ignore the *Subject* field.

To make a self-signed certificate that should work on modern browsers, create an OpenSSL config file similar to the following and save it as `openssl.cnf`:

```
######################################################
# OpenSSL config to generate a self-signed certificate
#
# Create certificate with:
# openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -days 720 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.pem -config openssl.cnf
#
# Remove the -nodes option if you want to secure your private key with a passphrase
#
######################################################

################ Req Section ################
# This is used by the `openssl req` command
# to create a certificate request and by the
# `openssl req -x509` command to create a
# self-signed certificate.

[ req ]

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048

# The message digest for self-signing the certificate
# sha1 or sha256 for best compatability, although most
# OpenSSL digest algorithm can be used.
# md4,md5,mdc2,rmd160,sha1,sha256
default_md = sha256

# Don't prompt for the DN, use configured values instead
# This saves having to type in your DN each time.

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default
distinguished_name = req_dn

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl req -x509` command
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[ req_dn ]

countryName            = GB
stateOrProvinceName    = Somewhere
organizationName       = Example
commonName             = Example Web Service

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always

# No basicConstraints extension is equal to CA:False
# basicConstraints      = critical, CA:False

keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.org
```

Run:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -days 720 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt -config openssl.cnf
```

Add the `selfsigned.crt` to the trust-anchor store of your browser.

If you now fix your DNS resolution (local DNS or `/etc/hosts` file) so that `www.example.org` or `www.example.com` points to `127.0.0.1` you can access `www.example.com` or `www.example.org` without Chrome complaining.

To test, run:

```
openssl s_server -cert selfsigned.crt -key selfsigned.key -www -accept 8443
```

Point your browser to `https://www.example.org:8443` - you should get a list of available cipher-suites and some session information. You should **not** get a certificate warning.

Comment: Great answer.  How does ‘@alt_names’ get populated?

Comment: @DanielK  By the [alt_names] section.

Comment: so in the /etc/hosts file I add 127.0.0.1 www.example.com and on another line ::1 www.example.com ? Is this correct ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: By the way for the last bit pointing to https://www.example.org:8443 after running openssl s_server -cert selfsigned.crt -key selfsigned.key -www -accept 8443 just gives me "the site can't be reached www.example.org took too long to respond". and the message i got after running openssl is using default DH parameters ACCEPT

Comment: Did you add `www.example.org` to your `/etc/hosts` file?  Alternatively, use `www.example.com` in the `openssl s_server` command.

Comment: openssl:Error: 's_serv' is an invalid command.

Comment: @NathanB - thanks, fixed the typo now.  It should read `s_server`.